# Android App is not searchable by tablets on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

When I uploaded the apk, I got this warning on the Developer Console:

> **Design your app for tablets**
>
> Your APK does not seem to be designed for tablets.

I know there are some questions targeting the same issue but cases are always different, so I'm putting here the permissions & features I'm requesting in the `AndroidManifest.xml` hoping for a more specific answer to this case:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: just because you get that warning does not mean tablet cant find your app, did you actually try searching for it from a tablet?

Comment: also you have the permission to send SMS messages, if a tablet does not have the ability to send them it wont be available

Comment: @tyczj I actually tried to search from tablets but my app didn't show up in search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the official [Tablet App Quality guide](https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements):

> Check the manifest for [`<permission>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) elements that [imply hardware feature requirements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions) that not be appropriate for tablets. If you find such permissions, make sure to explicitly declare a corresponding  element for the features and includes the android:required=”false” attribute.

So, I had to explicitly declare some features (used implicitly by permissions) as `false`, so the solution in my case is by adding this to the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

& of course handling the case when these features don't exist in the device.